# wp7 childbrowser error - uri string is too long

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, base64, childbrowser

I am using the ChildBrowser component in WP7/Cordova 2.2 application where I need to display the Base64 PDF content in the browser.

Following error `Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.` is thrown while opening the child browser with base64 data url.

I am not quite good with .NET so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example that reproduces this? If you're including a Base64encoded PDF document as part of the query string then you'll need to find a different approach as that only supports working with a length of a couple of thousand characters.

Comment: It is not part of the query string, i am creating a `data:application/pdf;base64,....` string and then opens the childbrowser with it. This works in `iOS`.

Comment: @MattLacey also the PDF size is little over 100kb

Comment: Base64Encoding typically increases size by about 130%. In that it's reporting that size is an issue have you tried with a smaller file? or a different file type (like a small image)?